# How to make river lines intact between confluences in QGIS？

Tags: qgis, line, rivers, qgis-2.2

I got a river shapefile below,

[image]

and I found that there are many fragmental lines in this line shapefile, like,

[image]

and,

[image]

Most of these are located around the confluence(node), and how can I do to efficiently merge them into the nearby large line object, making whole shapefile containing only intact line segments between confluences(nodes)？

Comment: Do you have access to ESRI? Assuming that there are no attributes to preserve I would dissolve into a single multipart feature and then planarize in an edit session of ArcMap. I don't know of any function in OGR/QGIS that would perform a planarize but there might be an explode multipart into single part that works in a similar manner.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson thanks, I want to use QGIS to do this.

Answer (score 1):

QGIS **Disolve** can solve this issue.

1. In your river layer, select linestrings you want to merge.
2. Go to menu and activate `Vector | Geoprocessing Tools | Dissolve`
3. Make sure that your river layer is selected as `Input layer`.
4. Select option `Dissolve all` (to dissolve all selected linestrings, without specifying the ID).

If the selected line segments are not intact, `Dissolve` tool gives a multipart feature. In such cases the line layer has to be topologically cleaned beforehand.

Answer (score -1):

Go to settings
Go to snapping options
Select river layer
Select pixcel from dragdown menu
Choose around 10 pixcel for snapping limit.

Comment: I'm not sure how the snapping option will change the pre-existing data. Please consider expanding the question clearly answering the OP's question.

Comment: I tried, but like @DevdattaTengshe said, the data seems not change.